# Minimized video call and shared view with Zoom SDK

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, sdk, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to integrate Zoom SDK meetings in an Android app. I've struggled for a while now with using the custom meeting ui and learning how to use Zoom's video view called `MobileRTCVideoView`. Here's the interface I would like to create:

[image: custom meeting ui with minimized user video views and a shared view]

What I've tried:

- Studied Zoom's sample apps on [Github](https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-android).
- Studied Zoom's [documentation](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/android/mastering-zoom-sdk/in-meeting-function/customized-meeting-ui/overview) for customized meeting ui.
- [Asked](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/custom-meeting-ui-resized-user-cam-shared-view/15718) on the developer forum.
- Read [related threads](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/android-video-call-minimization/224/8) on the developer forum.

However, I still don't understand how to implement it, and would very much appreciate some explanation as to how to use `MobileRTCVideoView`, and achieving the meeting ui illustrated on the image. The meetings should only hold up to two users at a time.

I initialize the Zoom SDK with API Key and Secret, and use email login. I enable the custom meeting ui with:

```
zoomSDK!!.meetingSettingsHelper.isCustomizedMeetingUIEnabled=true
```

I start an instant meeting with:

```
val meetingService=zoomSDK!!.meetingService
val opts=InstantMeetingOptions()
opts.no_driving_mode = true
opts.no_invite = false
opts.no_meeting_end_message = false
opts.no_titlebar = false
opts.no_bottom_toolbar = false
opts.no_dial_in_via_phone = true
opts.no_dial_out_to_phone = true
opts.no_disconnect_audio = true
meetingService.startInstantMeeting(this,opts)
```

I've tried to follow the sample apps by creating another activity for the custom meetings, but apparently the class and the code is not complete:

```
class CustomMeetingActivity: FragmentActivity() {

    private var zoomSDK:ZoomSDK?=null
    private var inflater:LayoutInflater?=null
    private var normal_view:View?=null
    private var video_view:MobileRTCVideoView?=null
    private var video_manager:MobileRTCVideoViewManager?=null
    private var meeting_service:MeetingService?=null
    private var in_meeting_service:InMeetingService?=null
    private var share_view:MobileRTCShareView?=null
    private var meeting_video_view:FrameLayout?=null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        zoomSDK=ZoomSDK.getInstance()
        meeting_service = ZoomSDK.getInstance().meetingService
        in_meeting_service=ZoomSDK.getInstance().inMeetingService
        if(meeting_service==null || in_meeting_service==null){finish();return}

        setContentView(R.layout.custom_meeting_layout)

        inflater=layoutInflater;
        normal_view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.meeting_content_normal,null)
        meeting_video_view = findViewById<View>(R.id.meetingVideoView) as FrameLayout
        share_view = findViewById<View>(R.id.sharingView) as MobileRTCShareView
        video_view=normal_view!!.findViewById(R.id.videoView) as MobileRTCVideoView

    }

}
```

Added the activity in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.mypackage.appname.CustomMeetingActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/ZMTheme.SubWindow">
    </activity>
```

Comment: hey, i am stuck in same situation. i have read your thread on developer forum on zoom and you get solution for this issue so can you please provide github link of your sample project or zoom sdk link because customized UI project is removed from github now.

Comment: post the layout file too

Answer (score 0):

Solid advice I can give is:

1. Override or reuse their existing Sample to get started. (Though their sample app looks like it was done in a rush)
2. Don't user their styles, override their styles and use them.
3. Scan/Study the MyMeetingActivity. Most of the heavy lifting is done in it already.
4. Check both of their samples. If you cannot figure out sharedView from MyMeetingActivity, then it looks like you haven't studied hard enough

I have worked a lot on this over the last few weeks. Customized UI is working well. I am looking to make the Gallery view. We have loads of features and functionality that we added and reused. Over all it was a bumpy ride, but still went smooth as I spent time on it.

I don't understand why this question is not yet answered. Unfortunately I am too busy to actually write code out for you, especially since I am not even developing in Kotlin. Sorry. Hope you figure it. If I implement the gallery view, then maybe I can come back and give you some pointers. Good Luck