# Not able to integrate zoom in my application

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, zoom-sdk

I am trying to integrate zoom in my application.
For that, I followed this link [https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/android/getting-started/prerequisites]

I've created a new android project where I've imported the .aar files from zoom SDK as well as imported the dependencies but when I try to run this in my main application I get this error.

```
error: cannot find symbol
        JoinMeetingOptions opts = ZoomMeetingUISettingHelper.getJoinMeetingOptions();
                                  ^
  symbol:   variable ZoomMeetingUISettingHelper
  location: class MainActivity
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation project(path: ':commonlib')
    implementation project(path: ':mobilertc')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'

}
```

MainActivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import us.zoom.sdk.JoinMeetingOptions;
import us.zoom.sdk.JoinMeetingParams;
import us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDK;
import us.zoom.sdk.ZoomSDKInitializeListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ZoomSDK sdk = ZoomSDK.getInstance();
MeetingService meetingService = sdk.getMeetingService();

        sdk.initialize(this, App_Key, App_Secret, ZoomSDKInitializeListener);

        JoinMeetingOptions opts = ZoomMeetingUISettingHelper.getJoinMeetingOptions();
        JoinMeetingParams params = new JoinMeetingParams();
        params.displayName = displayName;
        params.meetingNo = meetingNo;
        params.password = meetingPassword;
        meetingService.joinMeetingWithParams(context, params, opts);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've imported the ones it allowed me to import...for ZoomMeetingUISettingHelper there is no import available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import both **commonlib.aar** and **mobilertc.aar** . And inside your gradle paste this two
**implementation project(":commonlib")**
***implementation project(":mobilertc")***

Answer (score 4):

Suggestion 1:

1. Check the order of imports.
2. Clean gradle cache at `C:\Users\<USER>\.gradle\cache`
3. In Android Studio `Invalidate & Restart`
4. Oh yeah found the problem: (You should have just done suggestion 2)

```
import com.***.inmeetingfunction.customizedmeetingui.MyMeetingActivity;
import com.***.inmeetingfunction.customizedmeetingui.SimpleZoomUIDelegate;
import com.***.inmeetingfunction.customizedmeetingui.view.MeetingWindowHelper;
import com.***.inmeetingfunction.zoommeetingui.ZoomMeetingUISettingHelper;
```

This class `ZoomMeetingUISettingHelper` is not part of the SDK. Its a custom class. That's why you cannot import it. `Just copy it over from the sample.`

Suggestion 2:

Same as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668551/minimized-video-call-and-shared-view-with-zoom-sdk/65314535#65314535): Just start with their sample application. Why you trying to re-invent the wheel importing libraries and stuff. Just use their existing sample as a starting point, and then go from there, create your new Activities, Views etc. Just don't use their Activities and Views you don't need. Once you are done with all the functionality, you can remove and do some cleaning up.